# Convert TIFF image (Mosaic Dataset) to Polygon Feature

Tags: raster, arctoolbox

I have geo-referenced TIFF images, I need to convert them in polygon feature class. I have used `Raster to Polygon` Toolbox from ArcGIS but it ran for more then 48 hours and did not give me meaningful data.

I need some suggestion on this so that I can get all polygon features from TIFF images.  My images are scanned copy of polyvinyl sheets.

Comment: When reporting non-functional behavior of tools that do work, it helps to provide the actual command and output, as reported in the Geoprocessing -? Results... dialog box (explode the failed command and Copy As Python Snippet to get the command, and the Messages for the output).

Comment: @Bhaskar Singh, what are the data values in your TIFF Rasters? Is it classified values like 1,2,3 or floating values ranging from -1 to +1 for example?

Comment: @GurminderBharani values are in floating range.

Answer (score 2):

The values being in the floating range explains the long processing time. Since it is a resource-intensive task to club similar floating values.

Please refer the following documentation: 
https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012554

Comment: I will implement given work around and validate the output. If everything works well then i would mark this an answer.

Comment: @BhaskarSingh Sure!